# Definitely Typed adding library to TypeScript project

Tags: typescript

I have any issue with adding ChartJS library from DefinitelyTyped set. I've added the file (chart.d.ts from the https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) to the project, and referenced it through:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/chartjs/chart.d.ts" />
```

However, when I run the code, "Chart" is not defined in:

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

All other libraries work as expected (jQuery.d.ts, angular.d.ts etc).

Answer:

Turns out I didn't added the original JS library to the project - I only added the xx.d.ts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I run the code, "Chart" is not defined in:

## Assuming the error is at *runtime*

Just because you added the `.d.ts` file doesn't actually bring in the JavaScript library. Check the library docs on how to do that: http://www.chartjs.org/

## Error at *compile time*

Unlikely based on your code `new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);`, but just in case ... its good to check how the definitions are intended to be used by looking at the test file: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chartjs/chart-tests.ts

Comment: Hi! 
Thanks for your answer! I get the error at runtime - I will try your answers in a sec, and let you know how they work!

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to include the original chart.js, which I didn't know :) I am newbie in TyepScript. Thanks anyways!